# How can I print a PDF document on multiple pages?

Tags: 12.04, printing, pdf

I'd like to print a single page PDF document on 2 or 4 pages.

Is there a way to do that on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the job: [command line PDF poster printer](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pdfposter.1.html)

To install, use `apt-get` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install pdfposter
```

Example of usage for A4 -> A2 size:

```
$ pdfposter -v -mA4 -pA2 input_A4.pdf output_4_A4.pdf
---- processing page 1 -----
Deciding for 2 column and 2 row of portrait pages.
```

Comment: Tried it just now under Ubuntu 16.04, and it turned an A4 poster into two blank pages to tile to make an A3 poster. I.e., it didn't work.
$ pdfposter -v -mA4 -pA3 marketing/posters/LeethDossierPoster-Freecon2018.pdf  marketing/posters/Frecon2018_A3.pdf
---- processing page 1 -----
Deciding for 1 columns and 3 row of landscape pages.
$ pdfposter -v -mA4 -s 1.4 marketing/posters/LeethDossierPoster-Freecon2018.pdf  marketing/posters/Freecon2018_A3.pdf
---- processing page 1 -----
Deciding for 1 columns and 2 row of landscape pages.

Comment: Works for me. I'm printing an infographic which is much taller than it is wide and I want to print it across multiple pages in one column. 
`pdfposter -p 1x2a4 in.pdf out_down_2_A4_pages.pdf`
`pdfposter -p 1x3a4 in.pdf out_down_3_A4_pages.pdf`
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pdfposter.1.html
`sudo yum install pdfposter`

Comment: Not working properly for me. Tried it to expand a familylines graphical report from Gramps (genealogical program) but it loses the lines that connect inidividuals.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Razor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) [image]

1. First Print your PDF to File ( As Image , as png or jpeg )
2. Then use this tool to print it over to as many pages as you wish

This technique is called **Image OR Document Stitching.**

Source : [Document on multiple pages](http://biggenius.org/printing-a-page-on-multiple-sheets/)

Answer (score 1):

Lot of years later, but I tried pdfposter and realized that there is no overlap option. Sometimes it could be a problem, with printer margins for example.
So I used [pdfarranger](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger):

1. Import original PDF
2. Duplicate page
3. Crop the bottom of the first page less than 50% to include overlap (48% for example)
4. Crop the top of the second page the same amount
5. Export PDF
6. Optional. Print the exported PDF file to a new PDF at the desired page size to see the final appearance on the printed page.