# printing: how to disable the -fit-to-page option to printing?

Tags: printing, pdf, scaling

Several threads describe applying the -fit-to-page to the `lp` or `lpr` commands, to make an image, ps or pdf, fit to one page.

This seems now to have become the default behaviour, however, and it is precisely what I do *not* want. I have a pdf file that would be quite larger than an A4 sheet (the only format my printer handles) but whenever I print it, it gets reduced so as to entirely fit the A4 sheet.

I should like to get a sequence of A4 sheets that can be joined to produce the complete image, or at least a single A4 sheet with (for example) the lower left corner of the image.

Is there any option to add to `lp` or `lpr`? I tried `lpr -o scaling=100` with no success. Do I need a separate utility to "slice up" the pdf file into A4-size printable portions?

Info: printer is Brother HL5350, Ubuntu is `PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"`

```
pdfinfo OCETDS568.pdf 
Author:         anonymous
Producer:       
CreationDate:   Thu Nov 20 11:29:00 2014 GMT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      2589.12 x 3741.12 pts
Page rot:       0
File size:      696464 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

pdfposter does the trick.
Also see [How can I print a PDF document on multiple pages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186867/how-can-i-print-a-pdf-document-on-multiple-pages)
In fact it seems I posted a double question, having searched before asking, but with less than optimal search terms, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through [cups-filters](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters) documentation, I found that scaling depends not only on printer default settings, but it's also affected by PDD file (if used) default settings, and the filters used by CUPS in the process.

So, the best option is to pass an argument explicitly to `lp` command instead of depending on the default value set by any of the layers.

The filters used by CUPS to process your file depend on the definitions expressed on the PPD file but, in general, a PDF source file will pass through the `pdftopdf` filter, and an image source file will pass through `imagetopdf` or `imagetoraster`, depending on printer capabilities.

According to the documentation from link above:

- When printing an image:

```
    IMAGE PRINTING DEFAULT CHANGED TO "SCALE TO FIT"

    Compared to the PostScript-based original CUPS filters there is a
    change of defaults: The imagetopdf and imagetoraster filters print
    in "scale-to-fit" mode (image is scaled to fill one page but
    nothing of the image being cut off) by default.

    This is done to support photo printing via AirPrint. The photo
    apps on Apple's iOS devices send print jobs as JPEG images and do
    not allow to set any options like "scaling" or the page size. With
    "scale-to-fit" mode set by default, the iOS photos come out on one
    page, as expected.

    To get back to the old behavior, supply one of the options
    "nofitplot" "filplot=Off", "nofit-to-page", or "fit-to-page=Off".
```

- When printing a PDF:

```
2) Page autorotate

pdftopdf automatically rotates pages to the same orientation,
instead of (e.g. fitplot) scaling them down unrotated.
This behavier can be controlled by

  pdfAutorotate / nopdfAutorotate

Specifically, if a PDF file contains pages with page width greater than
page height (a landscape page), such pages are automatically rotated
anticlockwise by 90 degrees, unless the PPD file specifies
"*LandscapeOrientation: Minus90". In this case, clockwise rotation is used.
To turn off the feature on a job-by-job basis use

  lp -d <print_queue_name> -o nopdfAutorotate <document>
```